# How to send a post request related to a group STEAM?

Tags: python, post, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

Is it possible to somehow send a post request to leave a comment in the steam community.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Steam Web API](https://steamcommunity.com/dev), but I don't think there is any public API to do that. You might still be able to do it with something like puppeteer (web automation)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask